# What are the ***transfer programs*** in the passage?

Tags: meaning

What are the ***transfer programs*** in the passage? I've looked up the phrase in the dictionaries to no avail.

> Both the budget deficit and federal debt have soared during the recent
> financial crisis and recession. During 2009－2010, nearly 40 percent of
> federal expenditures were financed by borrowing. The huge recent
> federal deficits have pushed the federal debt to levels not seen since
> the years immediately following World War II. The rapid growth of
> baby-boomer retirees in the decade immediately ahead will mean higher
> spending levels and larger and larger deficits for both Social
> Security and Medicare. Moreover, more than half of Americans age 18
> and older derive benefits from various ***transfer programs***, while
> paying little or no personal income tax. All of these factors are
> going to make it extremely difficult to slow the growth of federal
> spending and keep the debt from ballooning out of control. Projections
> indicate that the net federal debt will rise to 90 percent of GDP by
> 2019, and many believe it will be even higher unless constructive
> action is taken soon.

[Macroeconomics: Private and Public Choice](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=RFk8AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA478&lpg=PA478&dq=All%20of%20these%20factors%20are%20going%20to%20make%20it%20extremely%20difficult%20to%20slow%20the%20growth%20of%20federal%20spending%20and%20keep%20the%20debt%20from%20ballooning%20out%20of%20control.&source=bl&ots=Ehs6aoU8-Z&sig=ACfU3U2YST0YREZOBQyWKLMaBbE9NVdmTA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjjvGX0LDyAhWLZ94KHbxGAB4Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=All%20of%20these%20factors%20are%20going%20to%20make%20it%20extremely%20difficult%20to%20slow%20the%20growth%20of%20federal%20spending%20and%20keep%20the%20debt%20from%20ballooning%20out%20of%20control.&f=false)

Comment: It is a programme which involves the transfer of something (in this case probably money) from one person to another.  Try doing an on-line search for _transfer payments_.

Comment: Consider asking at [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](https://money.stackexchange.com/)